# Intent for generated listview app stopped working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I am trying to run an android application where I have a `MainActivity` which consists of a generated `ListView` of `TextView` items and an Intent so that when the user clicks on the first item in the list view, he goes to a second activity named `PortalActivity`. This is what I have tried to do so far. When I try to run it in eclipse android emulator, it shows this popup that *'Unfortunately, myApp stopped working'.*

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
    final String[] menuItems = {"Portal", "Settings", "Help", "About"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, R.id.listview_tv, menuItems));

         ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_tv);
         yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
         {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)    {
                  if (position == 0)
                  {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PortalActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                  }
              }
         });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

listview_item.xml: (layout for Main Activity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/listview_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="TextView"  
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and PortalActivity is just an activity with another defined layout. I'm sure the problem is around the intent since when commenting it, the app runs and shows the list view and the layout for portal activity is also working fine.

This is the StackTrace in Log Cat

```
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590): Process: com.example.androidexample, PID: 1590
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidexample/com.example.androidexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at com.example.androidexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-06 13:05:35.167: E/AndroidRuntime(1590):     ... 11 more
```

Does someone have any idea what is wrong please? I am very new to Android so thanks for any help :)

Comment: You should look in the logcat and post the error and stacktrace that you will find there.

Comment: Do you have `PortalActivity` in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes PortalActivity is included in AndroidManifest.xml and just included the errors in log cat. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call

```
     ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_tv);
```

returns `null` because there is no `ListView` in the layout with the resource ID `R.id.listview_tv`. Then the following line

```
     yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
```

gets a `NullPointerException` because `yourListView` is null.

Since you are extending `ListActivity`, to get the `ListView` widget you need to call `getListView()` like this:

```
ListView yourListView = getListView();
```

Comment: why is setContentView() called though and should I call it on 'this'?

Comment: You need to call `setContentView()` to tell Android what your activity's view layout looks like. You've got an XML file that describes your activity's layout. in `onCreate()`, just after calling `super.onCreate()` you need to call `setContentView()` and pass it the resource name of your layout. Something like `R.layout.custom_list_activity_view`

Comment: I just included 'setContentView(R.layout.listview_item);' but it still isnt running

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry. `ListActivity` has a default layout. This isn't the problem. The problem is that you need to call a specific method to get the default `ListView`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Since you are using the default `ListView` you should remove the call to `setContentView()` and use `getListView()` as I explained above. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: yes that was the problem. everything worked as expected. Thank you so much :)